# Arduino Library to make http post request with bearer authentication

Tags: wifi, http

I want to make an Http Post request with Bearer Authentication to my api using my Arduino Mkr Wifi 1010, but I couldn't find the appropriate library to do something like this (code generated with one made with Postman):

```
    POST /api/v1/rilevamento/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Host: www.....:8082
Authorization: Bearer eyJhb.......
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 233

{
    "id": 0,
    "dispositivo": "sesto",
    "nomeutente": "MyName",
    "cognomeutente": "MySurname",
    "mailutente": "name@email.it",
    "data": "2020-11-23T09:23:03.142+00:00",
    "temperatura": 37.5
}
```

Can you tell me where to find this library? I tried WifiNiNa httpClient, ArduinoHttpClient, HTTPClient and other but I couldn't  get any response or even enter in the method of my api on debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Authorization" is simply an HTTP header.  So add it in your request like:

```
http.addHeader("Authorization", token);
```

The value of "token" is just the string "Bearer " followed by your authorization string.  Don't neglect the SPACE after the word "Bearer".  It will look like:

> "Bearer eyJhb......"

On the Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 you use the WiFiNINA library which is slightly different.  Here is some example code:

```
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    client.println("POST /test/post.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.targetserver.com");
    client.println(authorizationHeader);
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(postData.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(postData);
  }
```

The variable `authorizationHeader` will have the "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx...." authorization string.

Or you can replace the `client.println(authorizationHeader);` by:

```
client.print("Authorization: Bearer ");
client.print(token);
```

to avoid dealing with concatenations, etc.

`client` can be an instance of `WiFiSSLClient` which works with both `WiFi101` and `WiFiNINA`.

Comment: I believe this is made with HTTPClient which is for ESP modules, can I use it with my MKR Wifi?

Comment: With the MKR WiFi 1010 you use the WiFiNINA library which is slightly different.  I've updated my answer with the relevant details.